# C# can't remove custom label from chart

Tags: c#

I want to remove a custom label from the specific position in chart C#

row data is a list in which data is filled by `datagrid`

```
foreach (var item in rowdata)
{ 
    if (!(this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Contains(checkedListBox1.SelectedItem)))
    {
        if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            var s = new CustomLabel(temp + 1.5, m + 1.5, item, labelrow, LabelMarkStyle.LineSideMark);

            this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(s);
        }
        else
        {
            var s = new CustomLabel(temp + 1.5, m + 1.5, item, labelrow, LabelMarkStyle.LineSideMark);

            mb = this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.IndexOf(s);
            this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.RemoveAt(mb);
        }
    }
    temp = m;
    m++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (var item in rowdata)
{ 
    if (!(this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Contains(checkedListBox1.SelectedItem)))
    {
        if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            var s = new CustomLabel(temp + 1.5, m + 1.5, item, labelrow, LabelMarkStyle.LineSideMark);

            this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(s);

        }
        else
        {
            // You can make this filter more specific if necessary
            var remLabel = this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels
                .SingleOrDefault(cl=>cl.FromPosition == temp + 1.5 
                                     && cl.ToPosition == m + 1.5);
            if (remLabel != null)
                this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Remove(remLabel);
        }
    }
    temp = m;
    m++;
}
```

The problem with your code is that the object reference is being compared.  The new object you are trying to remove isn't in the collection.  Likely your `mb` variable is always -1.

Comment: it is giving this exception "Sequence contains more than one matching element"

Comment: here is my previous code in which data is filling in list from gridview